# Flock command in AIX

Tags: shell, aix, flock

when I was trying to use flock in AIX box I was getting flock not found. System admin has installed util-linux package but he said flock executable is not available in AIX. Please let me know how to get flock command in AIX??

Answer (score 2):

You can compile `flock.c` from package `util-linux`, but it won't have the whole functionality of the linux version:

1. `flock -n <handle>` doesn't work, because on AIX, child and parent processes don't share file-locks.
2. With option `-w <timeout>` it will wait forever (if timeout is non-zero), as `flock(2)` on AIX doesn't return with errno=EINTR when a timer fires (SIGALRM).

Here's an example that does work on AIX:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "x$1" = x-locked ]; then
    shift
else
    echo "Trying flock on 'flock.tmp'"
    if ! flock --verbose -w 0 flock.tmp "$0" -locked "$@"; then 
        echo 'Flock failed'
    fi
    exit
fi

echo "After flock -- sleeping 15 sec"
sleep 15
echo "Exiting"
```

Here is the flock version I compiled from source: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/flock.tgz

Answer (score -1):

This package I think has the flock command.  http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Util-linux